# Can't ping/acces router, but do have internet access

Tags: router, ping

I can't ping or acces my router on my default gateway IP 192.168.2.254 but i do have error-free internet acces. The reason I want to acces my router is to set up a IP camera. I can acces my router from any other laptop/device in this home network. Cabled or Wifi doens't matter. I can succesfully ping servers such as 8.8.8.8.

Entering the IP 192.168.2.254 in any browser gives the common errors 'page can not be displayed'.

I tried:

- disabeling all my firewalls/ant-virus software
- ipconfig/release ,ipconfig/renew ,ipconfig /flushdns ,netsh int ip reset c:\tcp.txt,netsh winsock reset
- Windows update

please find the ipconfig below. I 'am struggling with this for days now and I don't have any clue about how to solve this problem any further.

```
**Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:**

Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : F4-96-34-91-EE-9D
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e189:8e9e:5e05:c765%10(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.15(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : vrijdag 19 oktober 2018 12:07:56
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : zaterdag 20 oktober 2018 13:02:33
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 66360884
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-21-83-5A-92-AC-E2-D3-4C-EB-4A
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.2.254
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

And ping result:

```
**C:\Users\jurri>ping 192.168.2.254**

Pinging 192.168.2.254 with 32 bytes of data:
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.
General failure.

Ping statistics for 192.168.2.254:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

Comment: Who the F*** is General failure and what is he doing on your computer?

Comment: If it's true that "_I can acces my router from any other laptop/device in this home network_", then you can presumably set up your camera from elsewhere. If you use [WireShark](https://wireshark.com/index.php?/) on both computers you can compare the traces. Also, check the router's management settings to see if any MAC addresses are excluded from using the web interface.

Answer (score 0):

Some routers have configurations such that they don't respond to pings.. This is usually on the internet side and not on the LAN side but it's not impossible.
 In addition it is also common for routers to have their configuration page unresponsive while being accessed by a wireless network.

1. Connect your computer by a Ethernet cable.
2. Disable your wifi.
3. Try again to access your router

Should this fail be aware that routers with old firmware can have all sorts of problems. Consider performing a reset on your router. You can find instructions on this if you lookup your router model on the internet.
If after the reset you still experience this issue, it is entirely possible either of the following

- Your ISP has disallowed access to the configuration page on *their*
  router
- Your router is faulty. Consider replacement or a DIY firmware upgrade
- You found a bug in the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

A *General Failure* message on your PC usually indicates a problem with your DNS cache, or your PC is trying to use IPv6 instead of IPv4.  Try flushing the cache.  If that doesn't work, you may have to do a system restore.  Googling for *ping general failure* will give you other troubleshooting suggestions.